# Magnitude of ADR algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra

Let $A$ be a connected quiver algebra with $n$ simple modules and Jacobson radical $J$ and Loewy length $n+1$ (that is $J^{n+1}=0$ and $n$ is minimal with this property).
The ADR-algebra $B_A$ of $A$ is defined as $B_A:=End_A(A \oplus A/J \oplus A/J^2 \oplus ... \oplus A/J^n)$.
Recall that the magnitude (see http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/31/3/31-03.pdf ) of an algebra of finite global dimension and Cartan matrix $C$ is defined as the sum of all entries of the inverse of $C$.

> Question 1: Is the magnitude of $B_A$ equal to $n$?

In the special case when $A$ is a commutative Frobenius algebra, 
we have that the Cartan matrix $C$ of $B_A$ has entries $C_{k,t}=\dim(Hom_A(A/J^k,A/J^t))$, which should be equal to $dim(J^{max(0,t-k)}/J^t)$ in case I made no mistake, so it has an elementary interpretation.

> Question 2: Is the magnitude of $B_A$ equal to one in case $A$ is a commutative Frobenius algebra?

The questions are tested for many algebras with the computer, but of course there are too many algebras to have really good evidence.

(Question 2 is of course a special case of question 1, but here the Cartan matrix has a more elementary form to calculate explicitly).

For example let $A=K[x,y]/(x^2,y^2)$, then the Cartan matrix of $B_A$ is given by $C$=[ [ 1, 2, 1 ], [ 1, 3, 3 ], [ 1, 3, 4 ] ].
The inverse matrix is
[ [ 3, -5, 3 ], [ -1, 3, -2 ], [ 0, -1, 1 ] ], where the sum of all entries is equal to 1.